Observing random A TIMEOUT OCCURRED from memcache server node
I have a multithreaded C application running on different servers that interact with several memcached servers for get and set operations. However, I'm encountering a "TIMEOUT OCCURRED" error from the memcache client. Upon further debugging, I found the following error messages from the memcache client:
"No active_fd were found"
"(number_of == 0)"
Despite the fact that my memcached server has a max connection limit of 350,000, I'm still seeing the "No active_fd" error. I checked the file descriptor (FD) count on the memcached server, and it's in the range of 180,000-240,000, well below the connection limit. This issue is occurring across multiple memcache nodes.
Below is the output of the stats command from one of the affected memcache nodes:
STAT pid 4071861
STAT uptime 4844901
STAT time 1726827002
STAT version 1.6.14
STAT libevent 2.1.12-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 725810.175438
STAT rusage_system 930280.690591
STAT max_connections 350000
STAT curr_connections 248004
STAT total_connections 7529720
STAT rejected_connections 225645
STAT connection_structures 349737
STAT response_obj_oom 0
STAT response_obj_count 2
STAT response_obj_bytes 1048576
STAT read_buf_count 1271
STAT read_buf_bytes 20824064
STAT read_buf_bytes_free 19726336
STAT read_buf_oom 0
STAT reserved_fds 320
STAT cmd_get 34148258838
STAT cmd_set 268385628
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT cmd_touch 0
STAT cmd_meta 0
STAT get_hits 33891039588
STAT get_misses 257219250
STAT get_expired 47683935
STAT get_flushed 0
STAT delete_misses 0
STAT delete_hits 0
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT touch_hits 0
STAT touch_misses 0
STAT store_too_large 0
STAT store_no_memory 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 7399102294866
STAT bytes_written 197610478515533
STAT limit_maxbytes 10737418240
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT time_in_listen_disabled_us 0
STAT threads 64
STAT conn_yields 0
STAT hash_power_level 23
STAT hash_bytes 67108864
STAT hash_is_expanding 0
STAT slab_reassign_rescues 1209090
STAT slab_reassign_chunk_rescues 164994
STAT slab_reassign_evictions_nomem 0
STAT slab_reassign_inline_reclaim 25337
STAT slab_reassign_busy_items 1560073
STAT slab_reassign_busy_deletes 0
STAT slab_reassign_running 0
STAT slabs_moved 476357
STAT lru_crawler_running 0
STAT lru_crawler_starts 4372710
STAT lru_maintainer_juggles 6512594353
STAT malloc_fails 0
STAT log_worker_dropped 0
STAT log_worker_written 0
STAT log_watcher_skipped 0
STAT log_watcher_sent 0
STAT log_watchers 0
STAT unexpected_napi_ids 0
STAT round_robin_fallback 0
STAT bytes 2970398662
STAT curr_items 6959812
STAT total_items 269594703
STAT slab_global_page_pool 1161
STAT expired_unfetched 37921159
STAT evicted_unfetched 0
STAT evicted_active 0
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 13766009
STAT crawler_reclaimed 182550526
STAT crawler_items_checked 483847408323
STAT lrutail_reflocked 44354
STAT moves_to_cold 1944004772
STAT moves_to_warm 1970571839
STAT moves_within_lru 5170601542
STAT direct_reclaims 0
STAT lru_bumps_dropped 0
END


1] We check for hardware issue from client side and server side,(CPU, RAM, Storage, etc) everything is ok.
2] We check for network lantency, observe no latency in network
3] we print below information for debugging, but still no luck :( still observe randomness in issue observer from memcache server node
error_message = memcached_last_error_message(cache_handle[i].dstr_mc);
server_instance = memcached_server_by_key(cache_handle[i].dstr_mc, key, strlen(key), &rc);
server_hostname = memcached_server_name(server_instance);


If you think this is a question about your C code, then please post a [mre] of your code.  If not, then it is off-topic for this site.
